# Adding a parameter to an extended url with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a script to add parameters to a URL to use with a `if` statement for a layout change. It works with a structure like this:

```
/Computers/Desktops
```

on click to change layout:

```
/Computers/Desktops?param=list
```

and

```
/Computers/Desktops?param=grid
```

I'm using a filer that adds parameter, then the layout will change between something like this:

```
/Computers/Desktops?param=list&fss=HP+2GB
```

and on click:

```
/Computers/Desktops?param=grid&fss=HP+2GB
```

This works well, but I need to make this work for another structure that looks like this:

```
/Computers/Desktops/Apple/Apple-iMac-Core-i5-2-7-GHz-8-GB-1-TB-LED-2?prodid=30811
```

Here I want to add the parameter before `?prodid=30811` so the layout changes on click between

```
/Desktops/Apple/Apple-iMac-Core-i5-2-7-GHz-8-GB-1-TB-LED-2?param=list&prodid=30811

/Desktops/Apple/Apple-iMac-Core-i5-2-7-GHz-8-GB-1-TB-LED-2?param=grid&prodid=30811
```

I hoped I just could change `FSS` in my script to `prodid`, but this doesn't work. So why doesn't it work and why, and how do I do this instead? My `if`/`else` script already works, I just need the correct URL from the buttonclick.

```
$('.click3').on('click', function() {
    console.log("Clicked");
    var baseUrl =  window.location.href.split("?")[0];
    var fss = getParametersByName("fss");
    var params = getParametersByName("fss");

    if (params == "list") 
        param = "grid"; 
    else 
        param = "list";

    var newUrl = baseUrl + "?param=" + param;
    if ((fss).length > 0) 
        newUrl = newUrl + "&fss=" + fss;

    window.location.href = newUrl;

    function getParametersByName(name) { 
        name = name.replace(/[[]/, "\[").replace(/[]]/, "\]"); 
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"), 
            results = regex.exec(location.search); 
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: The order of the properties in the querystring makes no difference. You can just append `&prodid=XX` to the end of the URL.

Comment: Not sure I follow - the order of the properties needs to be param=list or grid before the default orderid for my script to work correctly - but I cant change my script to work with the orderid.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464372/inserting-a-string-at-a-variable-index/34464590#34464590

Comment: `the order of the properties needs to be param=list or grid before the default orderid for my script to work correctly` This isn't the case at all. The `getParametersByName` function is designed to retrieve the properties from the URL by name, not by position. The order makes no difference.

Comment: Well I disagree. If the url looks like Apple-iMac-Core-i5-2-7-GHz-8-GB-1-TB-LED-2?prodid=30811?param=list my site wont display the layout change corretcyly

Comment: if the url looks like this: /Apple-iMac-Core-i5-2-7-GHz-8-GB-1-TB-LED-2?param=list&prodid=30811 it switches the layout corretcly.

Comment: The script above also just replaces ?prodid=30811 with param=list or param=grid on click, instead of adding it.

Comment: Ok, for some reason.. It now works when I replace "fss" with "proid".. not sure why. Seems like this whole post was unnecessary :p thanks for the help though!

Comment: You had two ``?`` in your link of your comment instead of one ``?`` and one ``&``.